# Dagger Hilt impossible to inject kotlin data class

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am trying to use Dagger Hilt in order to inject a data class in my code. My goal is to be able to have a single data structure that I can inject everywhere.

I have defined a data class as below:

```
data class UserInfo @Inject constructor(
    var lastname: String,
    var firstname: String,
    var email: String)
```

I have tried to use this data class in my MainActivity as below:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var userInfo: UserInfo

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initValue()

    }
    
    fun initValue() {
        userInfo.email = "ste@gmail.com"

    }
```

I keep getting error like

```
public abstract static class SingletonC implements DriverApplication
```

I tried to add Singleton but it's also generating the issue.

I just try to have one single data class to store information and use this information everywhere in my code.

Any idea ?

Comment: Well how should dagger inject a data class, if you never told dagger, what values "lastname", "firstname" and "email" are. Yes, you are calling  "initValue()", but it would still not work, because hilt needs these values while creating the data class. One way to solve this might be to add default values

Comment: From where are you injecting values in data class? Is there any provider created?

Comment: @Anand it's basically why I was asking the forum.

Comment: The only way I could make this work was by using class instead of data class.